# How can I automatically make new tag in Mit App inventor when I want to add new items to TinyDB

Tags: app-inventor

I have max limit of 3 items I can add in database, and I can add the items in DB whenever I want to. 
How can I make it so when I have for example already 1 item in database and I want to add another one, it makes a new tag automatically?

[code blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeHBh.png)
[image]

For now I was trying to make a simple if statements to check if there is something under that tag, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The correct logic for the `checkDB` procedure would be

```
if not is text empty ...
then ...
```

you can find the **not** block in the Logic drawer and the **is text empty** block in the Text drawer
also the text in the socket `valueIfTagNotThere` should be an empty string